# Native PHP PDO vs. Phalcon PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phalcon

Are there any advantages of using Phalcon's Framework PDO Adapter rather than the PHP's native PDO?

As there's seems to be a bit of advance functionality lacking in the Phalcon framework regarding PDO. Is it even worth it? Are there also dramatic performance differences that outweigh using PHP’s native PDO?

Comment: Are you already using Phalcon?

Comment: What is an example of the missing functionality?

Comment: Tons of functions such as "rowCount" not existing, and the "affected rows" private object from the prepared execute tends to return back null A LOT of times when in fact rows have been affected such as in deleting (for an example). There's tons of other small things that end up adding up. So, I am wondering is it worth the headache to use Phalcon's PDO.. Note, this is functionality that is obviously required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, Databases adapters in Phalcon are created as a layer behind `Phalcon\Mvc\Model`. Thanks to this you have same interfaces for MySQL, Oracle or PosgreSQL Adapter.. Or for other adapter that you and me can create. That's why, as some kind of abstraction, Phalcon PDO is a little limited. **It needs to share same logic with another types of RDBMS.**

So if you don't want to use Models go with simple PHP PDO. But ask yourself where is the point of using MVC framework without Model layer :)

If you need more informations, follow this link: http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/db.html